# Change value of row to image based on cell value

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, visual-studio-2005

Hi everyone i am doing a windows form which is created in visual studio 2005, wherein it displays data in datagridview. I have a column "colImg" that will display 1 and 0. But i need to display a red image when the value of cell of colImg is 0 and green image when the value is 1. I have a code but the problem is it only displays image which is green but i have a values which is 0. Is there any problem on my code?

```
Private Sub grdView_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles grdView.CellFormatting
    If grdView.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name.Equals("colImg") Then
        Dim value As Integer
        If TypeOf e.Value Is Integer Then
            value = DirectCast(e.Value, Integer)
            e.Value = My.Resources.Resources.NotYet
        Else
            For i As Integer = 0 To grdView.RowCount
                If value = 0 Then
                    e.Value = My.Resources.Resources.Red

                Else
                    e.Value = My.Resources.Resources.Green
                End If
            Next

        End If
    End If
```

Comment: Why do you use `For .. Next` loop? I'm pretty sure that nested `if` is doing what you expect.

Comment: I tried to loop those value in my datagridview but when i didnt use loops the result is still the same. The cell having a value of 1 is not displays as green

Comment: Try this: `e.CellStyle.BackColor = If(e.Value=0, Color.Red, Color.Green)` inside `CellFormatting` event.

Comment: But i need to put is an image not a back color.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions for your question, I will provide one of them.

1. You need two columns in your `DataGrid`.
   One is to hold the raw data (0 or 1); in my example I called it `colValue`.
   The other is to hold only the image (red or green); named `colImg`.
   `colValue` is not shown in the grid :

   ```
   'Set colValue invisible which is first column in my example
   DataGridView1.Columns(0).Visible = False
   ```
2. Use the `CellValueChanged` event to set the image of the `colImg` cell:

   ```
   If e.ColumnIndex = 0 AndAlso Not isInit Then 'Value column has changed and we are not in Form Initializing
      Dim valueCell = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex)    
      Dim imgCell = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1) 'Whatever index your colImg is
      If Integer.Parse(valueCell.Value.ToString()) = 1 Then
          imgCell.Value = My.Resources.Green
      Else
          imgCell.Value = My.Resources.Red
      End If
   End If
   ```

   3. To avoid that the event code breaks when the `Form` and thus the `DataGridView` is being initilized I created a local variable `isInit` and set it before and after the initialization:

      ```
      Public Class Form1

        Private isInit As Boolean 

        Public Sub New()
            isInit = True
            InitializeComponent()
            isInit = False
            ...
       End Sub
        ...
      End Class
      ```

Sample Data:

```
 DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = 1
 DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(0).Value = 0
 DataGridView1.Rows(2).Cells(0).Value = 0
 DataGridView1.Rows(3).Cells(0).Value = 1
```

Outcome:
[image]